pritunl client profile sync failed
We recently changed the port value for web-console from default 443 to 8443 using command
# pritunl set app.server_port 8443

and restarted the pritunl process. But when connecting the Pritunl client an error occurs - it tries to use the previous old port value and the log contains:
    [2024-10-29 13:5:48][ERROR] Profiles: Failed to sync profile configuration
RequestError: Request:  Client error ssl=true hostname=IP-address port=old_value method=GET path=/key/sync/61ff20cbc1e709c149fd0572/63fa174a90ebae054ae4fd56/653644b488c49b9109058421/c82dad22605b05dd854ebefe8c5a05db ttl=5000
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED IP:old_value
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED IP:old_value
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16)

i.e. profile not synced. Due to the large number of client profiles, it is not convenient to import profiles manually each time. Is there any way for profile synchronization to work?

Adding this iptables rule on Pritunl server helped me:
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport old_value -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

